# RestKit: за и против

Tags: restkit, objective-c, ios, rest

Хотелось бы узнать мнение коллег о библиотеке `RestKit`.

Интересует именно **реальный опыт использования библиотеки**, а не ссылки на [проект на Гитхабе](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) или [документацию](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki): я уже достаточно хорошо ознакомился с документацией и прочитал несколько постов автора библиотеки на SO (особенно содержательным оказался [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962109/trying-to-make-a-post-request-with-restkit-and-map-the-response-to-core-data/13965675#13965675)).

После просмотра всего материала по `RestKit` наиболее ценным кодом в библиотеке мне показался код, т.н. `Object Mappings Engine`, решающий задачу автоматического связывания `JSON`-объектов с моделями `Core Data` на основе автоматического распознавания типов свойств соответствующих объектов:

```
RestKit leverages the highly dynamic Objective-C runtime to infer the developers desired intent by examining the type of the source and destination properties and performing appropriate type transformations.
```

...что выглядит очень привлекательной возможностью для того, чтобы перестать создавать большие объёмы соответствующего кода руками и положиться на, наверное, второй по популярности после `AFNetworking` проект на `Objective-C` среди проектов, связанных с `Networking` и `REST` с огромной коммунити и активностью. Как минимум, возникает соблазн выкрасть `Mapping Engine`, - я рассматваю такой вариант, так как очень комфортно себя чувствую со всеми остальными участниками этой схемы: `AFNetworking`, `Core Data`, `Concurrency (GCD + NSOperation + Threads)`.

Очень интересен ваш опыт, особенно интересны граничные случаи (например, пришлось отказаться от `Restkit` потому-то и тому-то, или, наоборот, случаи вроде "`RestKit` спас нас от верной гибели на долгие годы вперёд") и особенно интересны случаи употребления `RestKit` в сложных проектах (много сетевого взаимодействия, разнообразие данных и пр.).

Спасибо.

P.S. Интересно услышать персональное мнение **@AlexDenisov**, он явно [в курсе ;)](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/1429)

**ОБНОВЛЕНО ПОЗЖЕ**

Несмотря на то, что в этом топике уже есть принятый ответ, я буду рад любым другим ответам, описывающим реальный опыт использования RestKit. Спасибо.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Я очень давно заметил RestKit, когда он еще был 0.10.х-ой версии, но использовать его в реальном проекте удалось только около полугода назад, фактически это был мой первый опыт, довольно печальный. Около полутора месяцев назад я начал работу над новым проектом, и там я использую RK, это мой второй опыт, печали гораздо меньше.

##### tl;dr

1. RestKit очень крут и удобен при условии что у вас действительно RESTful API.
2. Как и во всем ПО в нем есть баги, причем порой очень необычные.

##### Опыт первый

Новый проект, пришел ПМ и сказал "Пишите спеки на API, ребята будут делать".
Радости было немеряно. На спеки мы командой из трех человек потратили два дня. Спеки были готовы, RESTful, все дела. После я начал писать тесты на апиху на стабах, писал дня три, был безумно счастлив.

И тут постепенно начали появляться первые endpoint'ы на серваке, причем апиха полностью не соответствовала тому что мы описали в спеках.

Вместо одного ресурса с GET/POST/etc было 4: getProducts, createProduct, etc...

Выпиливать RK я не решился, и стал адаптировать его под реальную апишку, здесь я и столкнулся с главным его минусом: оно работает идеально если у вас действительно RESTful API (собственно по этой причине я и не мог им пользоваться столь долгое время).

В принципе он сработал и в нашем случае, но это был оверхед: пришлось описывать descriptor'ы по несколько раз для разных путей одной сущности. Да и тесты пришлось выкинуть, потому что их поддержка с таким API была очень трудоемкой задачей.

##### Опыт второй

Новый проект, рядом ребята которые пишут API, чистейший RESTful API.

Поначалу даже с ровным рестом казалось что есть некий оверхед, потому как первые дни писл много кода для маппингов, роутов и дескрипторов, но спустя почти месяц когда все апи описано работа с сетью стала просто удовольствием, буквально три строчки - и все, ждем наши модели или ошибки (которые тоже очень удобно мапятся в модели).

Из минусов: внезапно столкнулся с [проблемой](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/177), сначала были мысли переписать апишку, пока не укатилось на прод, но я решил подождать и начал искать проблему.

[Решение](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/1496) меня очень удивило: по факту я изменил довольно серьезную часть кода, но ни один тест не свалился.

В итоге все еще жду, возможно таки прийдется переписать этот кусок апихи, чтоб не таскаться с патченой версией.

**P.S.** извиняюсь за столь большой объем и сумбурность изложения

**UPD**

##### Повторные запросы

Особо с такой темой не сталкивался, единственная похожая ситуация:

шлем запрос на авторизованный ресурс, в ответ приходит 401 Unauthorized, шлем логин/пасс на сервер, получаем токен и повторно шлем первый запрос.

Честно говоря есть ли такая возможность у RK я не знаю, но мой коллега обрабатывал этот кейс простым образом: если где-то приходит 401, то обработка уходит в другую ветку, где и выполняются все эти запросы.

Единственные "грабли" в этом решении в том, что приходится создавать новый `RKRequestOperation` (т.к. старый является закешированным, и повторно его послать не получится) и самому отправлять его в очередь (`enqueueRequestOperation:`).

А в целом нужно внимательно посмотреть доки/исходники, я еще не успел столкнутся с такой задачей :)

Comment: Было бы еще интересно узнать, как реализована в RK (или у вас) работа со сбоями сети? Пример: я еду по Киеву на маршрутке с Киевстаровским мобильным интернетом и он периодически отваливается. То есть как в RK (или вами) такие штуки хэндлятся: подхват оборванных запросов и отправка их заново?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ и добавление к ответу!

Comment: @AlexDenisov прошло 2 года - какиой сейчас фидбек? RestKit все еще используешь? С тех пор Mantle подрос (поддержка CD и прочие плюшки) и Afnetworking тоже постоянно развивается. имхо они вдвоем очень хорошо заменяют RestKit  и дают ту самую необходимую гибкость к порой не идеальному бэкэнду.

Comment: @skywinder ни одну из библиотек по своему выбору более не использую (все еще приходится с ними работать т.к. legacy), вообще после NSURLSession не вижу смысла юзать AFN, а Mantle я никогда не понимал в принципе, написать сериалайзер/десериалайзер руками не составляет большого труда, зато дает гибкость и чистоту кода которой нет в Mantle и подобных мапперах